# Tesla AC Motor Patent: Is this waveform 90 degrees out of phase in the diagram?

Tags: motor, ac, induction-motor

I'm referring the following pictured patent:
[image: Patent]

Specifically, this portion of the patent:
[image: AC Motor Patent]

When flipping and superimposing the two magnets in the picture below, in the middle of the image I see two wave forms 90 degrees out of phase, with acceleration.  I'm aware an accelerating magnetic field induces the current due to the Lorentz force:
[image: Flipped Magnets]

I'm curious if this means anything, is meaningless, or was Tesla's way of showing the physical laws in the patent?

Answer (score 5):

It's meaningless.

The illustrators that are used for drafting the final published form of a patent usually redraw anything the inventor has provided. This is why more or less all published patents from any given country have the same sort of look and feel to their drawings.

The 'waveforms' you are looking at are an illustrators' convention that there is some bulk material beyond what has been shown, which has been 'torn off' to leave ragged edges. While that on the south pole could look regular enough to be intended as a waveform, the north pole edge is much more irregular. To me, the overlapping 'waveforms' look to be nearer to antiphase (180 degrees) than 90.

I think if Tesla had been intending to leave an [Easter Egg](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Easter_egg_(media)) in the patent, they would have been better waveforms, and in quadrature phase.